# Getting the template reference inside a ngFor

Tags: angular

I am creating in a ngFor a

```
<mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let relatedDatastore of relatedDatastores">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header >
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <items-grid-component [gridId]="relatedDatastore.d_id" #grids></items-grid-component>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

I am trying to get those ItemGridCOmponent in order to store them in an array with their corresponding ID.

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.relatedGrids = new Map<string, ItemsGridComponent>();
    MyApiCall.subscribe((data:any) =>{
            this.relatedDatastores = data.related_datastores; // I populate the variable for ngFor here

            this.relatedDatastores.forEach(relatedDatastore => { // I want to store my newly create component with the ID of the element here
                let relatedGrid = this.grids._result.find(grid => {return grid.gridId === relatedDatastore.d_id});
                this.relatedGrids.set(relatedDatastore.d_id, relatedGrid);
            })
        }
    });
}
```

This would work, but _result is private.

I need to use the observable, but it's starting to get really messy...

Is there a way to do it differently?

Comment: change ``#grids`` to ``#grids{{i}}`` and access the index in ``ngFor``

Comment: It is not clear what you ask but I assume you want to use `Observable` to provide list to `ngFor`. If so, you may use `async` pipe like `*ngFor="let data of (observableData | async)"`

Comment: What do you want to do with your `ItemsGridComponent` in your parent component? Couldn't you do those things directly in the template?